# CakePHP Error: Class App\Controller\AuthComponent not found

Tags: authentication, cakephp, namespaces, cakephp-3.2

I'm working in CakePHP 3.2 and writing an admin panel where only admin can login.

There is a separate table `admins` to store admin credentials. There is `users` table also which is used for users to register/login from main application.

I have to use `admins` table to login in admin panel.

What I have done is.

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use Cake\Controller\Controller;
use Cake\Event\Event;


class AppController extends Controller
{

    public function initialize()
    {
        parent::initialize();

        $this->loadComponent('RequestHandler');
        $this->loadComponent('Flash');
        $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
          'loginAction' => [
            'controller' => 'Admins',
            'action' => 'login',
            'plugin' => 'Admins'
          ],
          'loginRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'ServiceRequests',
            'action' => 'index'
          ],
          'logoutRedirect' => [
            'controller' => 'Admins',
            'action' => 'login'
          ],
          'authenticate' => [
            'Form' => [
              'userModel' => 'Admin',
              'fields' => [
                'username' => 'email',
                'password' => 'password'
              ]
            ]
          ]
        ]);
    }

    public function beforeRender(Event $event)
    {
        if (!array_key_exists('_serialize', $this->viewVars) &&
            in_array($this->response->type(), ['application/json', 'application/xml'])
        ) {
            $this->set('_serialize', true);
        }
    }
}
```

`AdminsController.php`

```
<?php
namespace App\Controller;

use App\Controller\AppController;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use App\Controller\AuthComponent;

/**
 * Admins Controller
 *
 * @property \App\Model\Table\AdminsTable $Admins
 */
class AdminsController extends AppController
{
      public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
      {
          parent::beforeFilter($event);
          $this->Auth->allow('add');
          // Pass settings in using 'all'
          $this->Auth->config('authenticate', [
            AuthComponent::ALL => ['userModel' => 'Members'],
              'Basic',
              'Form'
          ]);
      }

    public function login()
    {
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $user = $this->Auth->identify();
            if ($user) {
                $this->Auth->setUser($user);
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
            }
            $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
        }
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
    }
}
```

But this is not working. and gives `Error: Class App\Controller\AuthComponent' not found`

Also I want to restrict access to all controllers and actions without login. Thats why there is no `$this->Auth->allow()` in `AppsController.php`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> use Cake\Controller\Component\AuthComponent;

Comment: ... and `Controller\Component` :)